# Is it true that OUT parameter must be assigned a value in PL/SQL?

Tags: oracle, plsql, out-parameters

```
create or replace procedure ppp(ot OUT number)
is
begin
null;
end;
/
```

This works fine on being called.

Comment: I think you answered your own question :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Test-runs show that it is essential but not mandatory.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg10pck.htm) on output parameters:

> Formal parameter acts like an uninitialized variable.

So it's fine if you don't specify a value.

```
DECLARE
  d  NUMBER;
BEGIN
  ppp( d );

  IF ( d IS NULL )
  THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line( 'NULL' );
  END IF;
END;
```

Writes NULL to the dbms output

Comment: From the same doc, '...must be assigned a value'.

Comment: @popstack Yes but the compiler won't prevent you not assigning values. From another doc: Also, before a stored procedure is exited, all OUT formal parameters must be assigned values. Otherwise, the values of corresponding actual parameters are indeterminate. (I agree with you it would be better if the compiler forced you to assign a value)

Answer (score 2):

From http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/08_subs.htm#917 :

> Like variables, OUT formal parameters are initialized to NULL.
>
> Before exiting a subprogram, explicitly assign values to all OUT formal parameters. Otherwise, the corresponding actual parameters will be null.